# Retrieving a list of the parameters defined in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle

How to go about retrieving a list of the parameters defined in the supplied stored procedure.  The database is Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the sql statement you should use:

```
select argument_name, in_out, data_type

from   all_arguments

where  owner = 'schema_name' and

       package_name = 'package_name or null' and

       object_name = 'sp_name'

order by position
```